# Oracle Join SQL Quest

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables as per below:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_STATUS ("UID" varchar2(7), "STAT_ID" varchar2(11)) ;
INSERT ALL 
    INTO USER_STATUS ("UID", "STAT_ID") VALUES ('UID_001', 'STAT_ID_001')
    INTO USER_STATUS ("UID", "STAT_ID") VALUES ('UID_001', NULL)
    INTO USER_STATUS ("UID", "STAT_ID") VALUES ('UID_001', NULL)
    INTO USER_STATUS ("UID", "STAT_ID") VALUES ('UID_002', 'STAT_ID_002')
    INTO USER_STATUS ("UID", "STAT_ID") VALUES ('UID_002', NULL)
    INTO USER_STATUS ("UID", "STAT_ID") VALUES ('UID_003', 'STAT_ID_003')
SELECT * FROM dual;


CREATE TABLE STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID" varchar2(11), "STAT_CODE" varchar2(11), "STAT_ID" varchar2(11), "STATUS" varchar2(20));
INSERT ALL 
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_001', 'ST_CODE_001', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Processing')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_002', 'ST_CODE_002', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Processing')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_003', 'ST_CODE_003', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Processing')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_004', 'ST_CODE_004', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Processing')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_005', 'ST_CODE_011', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Issue')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_006', 'ST_CODE_012', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Issue')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_007', 'ST_CODE_013', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Issue')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_008', 'ST_CODE_014', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Issue')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_009', 'ST_CODE_015', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Issue')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_010', 'ST_CODE_021', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Done')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_011', 'ST_CODE_022', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Done')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_012', 'ST_CODE_031', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Started')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_013', 'ST_CODE_032', 'STAT_ID_001', 'Started')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_014', 'ST_CODE_002', 'STAT_ID_002', 'Processing (Sent)')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_015', 'ST_CODE_004', 'STAT_ID_002', 'Processing (Waiting)')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS")  VALUES ('LKUP_ID_016', 'ST_CODE_014', 'STAT_ID_002', 'Issue in Prod')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS") VALUES ('LKUP_ID_017', 'ST_CODE_012', 'STAT_ID_002', 'Issue in Prod')
    INTO STATUS_LKUP ("LKUP_ID", "STAT_CODE", "STAT_ID", "STATUS")  VALUES ('LKUP_ID_018', 'ST_CODE_021', 'STAT_ID_002', 'Done')
SELECT * FROM dual;


CREATE TABLE CORE ("CORE_ID" varchar2(11), "STAT_CODE" varchar2(11));

INSERT ALL 
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_001', 'ST_CODE_001')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_002', 'ST_CODE_012')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_003', 'ST_CODE_021')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_004', 'ST_CODE_012')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_005', 'ST_CODE_012')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_006', 'ST_CODE_021')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_007', 'ST_CODE_001')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_008', 'ST_CODE_003')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_009', 'ST_CODE_012')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_010', 'ST_CODE_021')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_011', 'ST_CODE_001')
    INTO CORE ("CORE_ID", "STAT_CODE") VALUES ('CORE_ID_013', 'ST_CODE_004')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Check this -> **[Oracle SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05aa7)**

The table are created in Oracle DB. Now based on user's UID passed I need to retrieve their Cores with Statuses as per below:

**[Click here to view Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rth9K.png)**

So far I tried to retrieve results but can not able to join them.

```
SELECT STLK.STAT_CODE, STLK.STATUS FROM STATUS_LKUP STLK WHERE STLK.STAT_ID IN (SELECT USRST.STAT_ID FROM USER_STATUS USRST WHERE USRST.UID = 'UID_001');
```

Please help.

FYI: This is not a homework assignment. Actual tables are complicated and these are just converted for better explanation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you state the logic that is used in determining the result set?

Comment: +1 for the fiddle... :)

Comment: Logic is ..1. To pass UID to USER_STATUS table and get STAT_ID list. 2. Pass STAT_ID list from 1 to STATUS_LKUP table and get STAT_CODE list.  3. Pass STAT_CODE list to CORE table and CORE_ID list for that STAT_CODE.    Need to fetch CORE_ID, their STATUS, and STAT_CODE for particular UID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly straight forward join;

```
SELECT sl."STATUS", sl."STAT_CODE", c."CORE_ID"
FROM USER_STATUS us
JOIN STATUS_LKUP sl
  ON us."STAT_ID" = sl."STAT_ID"
JOIN CORE c
  ON c."STAT_CODE" = sl."STAT_CODE"
WHERE "UID" = 'UID_001'
ORDER BY "STATUS", "LKUP_ID"
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05aa7/25).

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems I am not good in Joins. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT l.STATUS, 
       l.STAT_CODE,
       c.CORE_ID
  FROM STATUS_LKUP l JOIN CORE c
    ON l.STAT_CODE = c.STAT_CODE JOIN USER_STATUS u
    ON l.STAT_ID = u.STAT_ID
 WHERE u."UID" = 'UID_002'
 ORDER BY l.STATUS DESC, l.STAT_CODE
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05aa7/26)**

Answer (score 0):

This version of the query works:

```
SELECT STLK.STAT_CODE, STLK.STATUS
FROM STATUS_LKUP STLK
WHERE STLK.STAT_ID IN (SELECT USRST.STAT_ID
                       FROM USER_STATUS USRST
                       WHERE USRST."UID" = 'UID_001'
                      );
```

`UID` is a reserved word in Oracle (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)), which is why it needs the double quotes.

Comment: The CORE_ID is not listed.  Need to fetch CORE_ID, their STATUS, and STAT_CODE for particular UID.